# Creating multiline labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

How can I apply Multiline label option in the label property?

Name field contains a lengthy name. I want to wrap it.

My QGIS version is 1.8.

Answer (score 23):

If you labels contain a new line character (`\n`) they will be automatically wrapped. If not you can apply a wrapping character in the **Advanced** section of the labeling tools

[image]

The label will be wrapped on the character supplied. If you want to wrap on space just insert a space.

Comment: Nathn W, where i add the "\n" sign?

Comment: 'Label1: '||"Label1"
||
'\nLabel2: '|| "Label2"
||
'\nLabel3: '|| "Label3"||

Answer (score 22):

Since **QGIS 2.4** there is very handy [new expression builder function](http://changelog.linfiniti.com/qgis/2.4.0/entry/new-expressions/) called **wordwrap** that will allow one to automatically wrap a lengthy string using as argument the ideal number of characters that a lime should have and ,optionally, a string delimiter (the default is space).

In the below example the field "sintaxon" is my lengthy values field.

[image]

Also notice that I can nest wordwrap several times if I want to use more than one string delimiter. In the example below it uses '-' and the default space.

[image]

Comment: This is not the best answer, but it was helpful to me as I wanted to split the label on different characters (space or dash). I had one case of dashes so used `IF("name"='Chester-le-Street', 'Chester-\nle-Street', name)`.

It's a hack, but it's good for my use.

Comment: You could also nest the expression twice to have both a max & min number of characters per line...

Comment: This is a great tip for lengthy labels. Thanks a lot !

Comment: how do i get into the expression dialog?

Comment: Click the Expression builder icon next to the column field. It looks like a Epsilon, a E.

Comment: `wordwrap` also available in QGIS 3.x