# "No-break space" for labels

Tags: qgis, labeling

My map has labels, which usually should break after the 14th character using "wordwrap":

wordwrap(name,14)

But sometimes I need to suppress the wraping. So I need to use a "No-break space" - is there one?

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with Postgis?

Comment: Not? I dont know.

Comment: `wordwrap(string, wrap_length, [delimiter_string])` is a [QGIS 2.4 feature](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109870/1872)

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this is to add an attribute field "WRAP" with a default value of something very high like 100, and then in place of the wrap length I use the value of that field. So: `wordwrap("NAME","WRAP")`

When I want a label to wrap I just change its "WRAP" attribute to the length I want. Of course you could set a low default value so that most of your labels wrap, then only change the ones you want to suppress.

There is a non-breaking space, by the way (on Mac it's option-space), but it does not seem to affect label wrapping. However, you *can* use it to bypass the word spacing value specified in label settings. This is helpful if, for example, you have a feature with a two-word proper name that you want grouped together, but separate from the feature descriptor. Thus: `St George     River` or `Elkton    -    White Marsh    Road`.