# Specifying Minimum and Maximum Word Wrap length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want my labels to fit nicely within polygons.

Based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109870/36886) to [Creating multiline labels in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30084/how-to-create-multiline-labels-in-qgis/109870#109870), I discovered the power of the `wordwrap` function in QGIS to make labels. However, I'm confused as to how I could specify a **minimum** AND a **maximum** length for wrapping: I'd like no line to be longer than say 13 characters, but I also don't want any line to only have 3 characters. Merely nesting the functions didn't work out for me

```
wordwrap( wordwrap( title(SITE_NAME) , -3), 13)
```

So I would like this label to fit someone nicely within its polygon
[image]

But if I only use the simple wordwrap it looks ridiculous.
[image]

And if I try to build an expression for wordwrap, e.g. `wordwrap( title("SITE_NAME") , -3)`, the "output preview" shows

> 'Anthony
>   A. Loconte
>   Memorial
>   Skating
>   Rink'

But the result is still the first image above.

**But** if I instead put `wordwrap( title("SITE_NAME") , -3)` in the `Label With` box (and make sure to disable all wordwrap functions. I get:
[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of how you want the strings to display.

Comment: @kttii, I'm beginning to think there might be a bug somewhere.

Comment: I'm not having the same issue with 32-bit 2.14.2-Essen...  wordwrap( title("SITE_NAME") , -3) works for me in the Expression dialog and Label With.

Comment: Weird, I'm using 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

From the help section for wordwrap()

> If wrap_length is positive the number represents the ideal maximum
>   number of characters to wrap

The key word being ***ideal*** ... wordwrap() wont break a 15 char word down at the 13th character.

---

**EDIT:** The function below needs further refinement for the sample string provided.

> 'Anthony A. Loconte Memorial Skating Rink'

This function will inject a specified delimiter at the max number specified:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def MaxWrap(inField, maxn, delim, feature, parent):
    return delim.join([inField[i:i+maxn] for i in range(0, len(inField), maxn)])
```

Then use wordwrap with the same delimiter and your minimum:

```
wordwrap(maxwrap( SITE_NAME, 13, '^-^'), -3, '^-^')
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for an exact split, more that I wanted each line to be between 3-13 characters, will update question soon

Comment: @raphael Did you try the function?  I tested it and it seems to me to do what you are asking.